# How to update TreeView child node based on parent node property

Tags: vb6

In a TreeView, how do I execute code only if a parent node's `Image` is 4 and any child's is 3?

```
If TreeView2.Nodes(ii).Image = 4 And TreeView2.Nodes(ii).Image = 3 Then.
```

For some reason this `If TreeView2.Nodes(ii).Image = 4` checks the parent and child , I don't know why.

I am trying to use `If TreeView2.Nodes(ii).parent.child.image=3` but it is not working right.

Comment: A `for` loop ends when its terminating condition is met. `For Each NodX2 In TreeView2.Nodes` ends when it reaches the last node in `TreeView2.Nodes`. The loop will run only once. It does not repeat unless you write code that causes it to repeat. Your question is pretty unclear - have you tried using the debugger to step through the code to see exactly what it's doing? Also, tracing the execution and logic will be much easier if you learn to properly indent your code. Your indentation is a real mess, which makes understanding the flow of execution difficult to follow.

Comment: `Treeview2.Nodes(ii).Image = 4 and TreeView2.Nodes(ii).Image = 3` cannot possibly be true. The `Nodes(ii).Image` cannot possibly be equal to both 4 and 3 at the same time. And `Nodes(ii).Parent.Child.Image` is the same as the image of the node itself - it's the child of the parent.

Comment: how do i check and validate if parent is = 4 and any child is = 3 before code executes

Comment: @KenWhite `Nodes(ii).Parent.Child.Image` is the `Image` of the first child of the parent, it's not necessarily the same as the node itself.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville: You're right. I could have stated that better. It's still not what the poster seems to be looking for, though, and it doesn't change that `Image = 4 and Image = 3` can't possibly be true. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite yes there's some reading between the lines that needs to be done with the question!

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville: But there shouldn't be. :-) The poster has the responsibility of clearly stating the problem and asking the question, so that it will be useful to future readers who may be trying to solve a similar problem. It's hard to tell if your problem is similar when you can't tell what this post is asking in the first place, and if you can't determine that the problem is similar, you can't determine whether you should consider the answer to it for your issue. If the question isn't clear, then it shouldn't be answered until it has been asked clearly.

Comment: @KenWhite indeed. With new contributors I try to help out first and let them get familiar with how things work on SO. Hopefully they get a good experience, come back and improve their questions as their code improves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TreeView2.Nodes(ii).parent` is always going to be Nothing. The top-level nodes in your TreeView don't have parents. When you use `TreeView2.Nodes(ii).parent.child` you are certain to get an error. Using `parent.child` would only be used to get the first child of the parent node which probably isn't what you are trying to do.

It sounds like you want to do the following:

```
Dim objRootNode As Node
Dim objChildNode As Node
Dim iRootCounter As Integer
Dim iChildCounter As Integer

For iRootCounter = 1 To TreeView1.Nodes.Count

    Set objRootNode = TreeView1.Nodes(iRootCounter)

    If objRootNode.Image = 4 Then

        Set objChildNode = objRootNode.Child ' Gets first child

        For iChildCounter = 1 To objRootNode.Children

            If objChildNode.Image = 3 Then
                ' Write your code here
            End If

            Set objChildNode = objChildNode.Next ' Get next node

        Next

    End If

Next
```

Add your code where it says `Write your code here`. This is where parent has `Image = 4` and child has `Image = 3`.

Comment: Happy to help. The TreeView is a little harder to work with than a normal tree structure like Folders and Files. You can iterate through top-level notes with a `For Each` statement (which is great because you just deal with individual objects) but you cannot do that with the children. You'd expect to be able to do `For Each objChild in objNode.Children` but that's not how it works with the TreeView.